# How to Clear the Database Value using Javascript Function

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

Suppose i have a Dynamic Value in a table , Lets say $value = 10
I want to clear this value from database by using some kind of Javascript function...

In simple, i want to make a system just like Facebook Notification 
As it receives a new notification, it increments the number and after read it clears the notification value..

please give me some idea

Comment: use status if unread the notification so status is 0 when read change it to 1using ajax you can update status..

Comment: No, that's not the concept which i'm currently using, 
http://demos.9lessons.info/notifications_css/index.php#
Look at this, i'm using this Javascript, and for Notification Bubble , its comes from Registration Entries

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is usually run in the user's Browser.  Is that where you have it?  If so, there is no *direct* way to reach back into your server to get to the Database.

You would need to use AJAX to invoke a separate server "web page", which could perform whatever database actions you like.